# Setting appid and secret at runtime MicrosoftBotConnector.Client returns 401

Tags: botframework

I am trying to connect using the connector client from an application outsides of my Bot.  When I set the appid and secret in config and use the parameterless constructor it connects as expected but when I try and set appid and secret at runtime I get a 401:

```
var connector = new ConnectorClient();         
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConnectorClientCredentials creds = new  
ConnectorClientCredentials("mybot", "key", "key(subid");
connector.Credentials = creds;
```

fails

```
        var connector = new ConnectorClient("mybot", "mykey");
```

fails

What am I missing.  All the docs only show parameterless connection using config.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error code 401 because of these two reasons,

1. The Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key header is missing or invalid
2. The BasicAuth with AppId and AppSecret are invalid

Please check whether you have used them correctly.